# Reverse Fourier transform in Unity

Tags: unity, audio

I was wondering if unity has any methods to convert frequency domain to time domain.

Comment: Is this not just a matter of summing several sines/cosines at your chosen time intervals, weighted by your frequency amplitudes?

Comment: Perhaps that is the case

Comment: The [second search result on Google](https://answers.unity.com/questions/974565/how-to-do-a-fft-in-unity.html) is a custom-made implementation on the Unity Forums.

Comment: @liggiorgio I would like to remind you that you get different search results in different countries. And what you linked to is not the function i asked for, please read the question one more time, slowly.

Comment: To answer your question: No. However, assuming you are trying to compute the idtft, this [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33686427/6334782) post shows how to do this in ~12 lines of C#.